# Javascript display error and page reload problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload, display

So my project this time is to create a game of tic tac toe against AI that will track the number of games won by the player, computer, and draws. My problem is that when a computer or player wins, or there is a draw, instead of adding to the win/lose/draw, it displays [object HTMLElement] followed by a 1 every time.

Also, starting a new game reloads the page, when I just want to clear the board. This also resets the number of wins/loss/draw, which I do not want.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0z632pz/

```
winCheck = function () {
if ((a1 == a2 && a1 == a3 && (a1 == "x")) ||
(b1 == b2 && b1 == b3 && (b1 == "x")) ||
(c1 == c2 && c1 == c3 && (c1 == "x")) ||
(a1 == b1 && a1 == c1 && (a1 == "x")) ||
(a2 == b2 && a2 == c2 && (a2 == "x")) ||
(a3 == b3 && a3 == c3 && (a3 == "x")) ||
(a1 == b2 && a1 == c3 && (a1 == "x")) ||
(a3 == b2 && a3 == c1 && (a3 == "x"))
) {
    xWin = true;
    winAlert();
    {
    playerWin = playerWin + 1;
    xWin = true;
    document.getElementById("playerWin").innerHTML = playerWin;
            }
```

This particularly is where the issue lies, I assume. Fixing just one will be perfect, as I can figure out the rest.

(Note: I had this to work for a drag/drop, but I couldn't get it to work on jsfiddle so I changed it to a clickable game, because that isn't my issue, so ignore the box of images.)

(Note2: I know this is probably something simple, but I've been awake a long time.. haha)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a location.reload that reloads the page on new game. And playerWin doesn't seem to be defined anywhere and doesn't have an initial value. Maybe declare it and set it to 0 to start with?

**UPDATE:**

To move all images back to the dragbox you'd do something like this

```
$('.ximage').each(function(){
    $('.dragbox').append($(this));
});
```

You'd have to add an ximage class to your images. Right now they have it as the id. Id is usually supposed to be unique.

Comment: Thank you, this solved both of my issues. Now just one remaining.. now that my page doesn't reload, my drag and drop images are gone for good once they are used. Is there a way to bring them back to the image box when I click "new game"?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting `playerWin`?

I suspect you are doing this `var playerWin = document.getElementById("playerWin");` which sets the variable to be the HTMLElement.